# How to return multiple return-types from a method

Tags: c#

I have a class with a method that has 3 return types:

```
public static class Analyzer
{
    public static (bool IsValid, bool IsNew, string SomeString) Analyze(string input)
    {
        // How do I return my 2 bools and string?
    }

    public static bool isValid((bool IsValid, bool IsNew, string SomeString) input)
    {

    }
}
```

I've setup Substring's to analyze my data. But I'm not certain how I set values for the values I'm expecting to return.

Comment: Why return different types and not a record/class that encompasses those types? e.g, `AnalyzerResult`

Comment: A [tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) or a class model which represents the return type.

Comment: @AnthonyForloney, I'm working on an Exercism.org challenge - the methods are setup this way already. Since they are expecting this, I can't change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `tuples` So you can return all three value in single braket `()`

Example : `return(true, false, "Any string...");`

To learn more about tuples

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples